# Is there any way to use order by clause in the table inside OnModelCreating in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I want to use the order by clause in the code below. The model and the View have StartDatetime field in it. So the order by should use startDatetime desc in the code.
Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            {
                var builder = modelBuilder.Entity<TestBookingsView>().ToTable("vw_Testbooking");
 
                SetKey(builder);
            }

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
```

Comment: Why you need to do this at the time of Model Creation?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, what is the issue if I do it here. I am thinking to add `builder.Property(v => v.StartDateTime).` but not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the OnModelCreating method to further configure the model that was discovered by convention from the entity types exposed in DbSet properties on your derived context.

In the OnModelCreating method, we could use the **Fluent API** configures Model, Entity and Property Configuration. Sample code as below:

```
public class SchoolDBContext: DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Write Fluent API configurations here

        //Property Configurations
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
                .Property(s => s.StudentId)
                .HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasDefaultValue(0)
                .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

More detail information about using Fluent API, check the following articles:

[Fluent API in Entity Framework Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx)

[Fluent API Configuration](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api)

> I want to use the order by clause in the code below. The model and the
> View have StartDatetime field in it. So the order by should use
> startDatetime desc in the code.

From your description, I assume might be you want to set the default order using Fluent API. In EF 6, there has a [`HasColumnOrder()` method](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/fluent-api-in-code-first.aspx) when using the Fluent API, but unfortunately, in EF core, it seems that this method not supported.

So, I suggest you could use the [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) or [OrderByDescending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=net-5.0) methods in the Query statement, instead of in the OnModelCreating method. You can refer this tutorial:[Tutorial: Add sorting, filtering, and paging - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-column-sort-links)